# Uninstall Xcode 4.2.1 after installing 4.3.1

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, uninstallation

I begrudgingly updated to Lion from snow leopard. I then updated XCode to 4.3.1 which as part of the update uninstalled 4.2 from snow leopard. I then realized that one of my other dev tools does not work with 4.3.1 at all, so I installed 4.2.1 along side it in the hopes of fixing things. It didn't. How do I remove 4.2.1 so I'm just left with 4.3.1?
I tried deleting 4.3.1 and re-installing hoping it would detect 4.2.1 and remove it like it did when I first upgraded but no dice.
Searching the web shows I need to run uninstall-devtools however I can't find it anywhere, /Developer doesn't exist...
Trying to re-install 4.2.1 in the hopes there was an uninstaller buried in there says "Xcode install assistant can't be installed because xcode is already installed" (it didn't say this the first time obviously) so I can't re-install without 4.3.1 in place in the hopes of getting a /Developer folder...
There appears to be no uninstall-devtools burried in 4.3.1 (and I have command line tools installed as well).
I can't find 4.2.1, maybe it didn't install (I forgot to check disc capacities before/after) but then why can't I try to install it again without any xcode installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that 4.2.1's installer actually installs an Xcode installer into your applications folder, which in turn actually installs Xcode. The solution is find the installed installer (makes so much sense...) and install Xcode an things behave as expected.

Comment: so much sense! Maybe, to make the process even better, the installed installer should install another installer somewhere else which then installs xcode!

Comment: It's a perfectly cromulent approach.

Answer (score 7):

Install Xcode 4.2.1 again and then uninstall it:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: Turns out the installer for 4.2.1 installs an *installer*... once I figured this out I got it sorted.

Comment: Worked perfectly. The version on the /Developer directory is the old Xcode, and the one in /Applications is the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The versions of Xcode that support installation into /Applications instead of /Developer in theory support being removed just via dragging to the trash.

In practice, I'm not sure I trust the process, and I wish there was still a more robust cleanup script.

Answer (score 0):

Search "Xcode 4.2" in spotlight or in finder it will find you the app then move it to trash .But dont forget to check version.